# PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials return false for some accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, directoryservices

I've created a simple web app for users can change their domain account password. I'm using ASP.NET 6.0 with System.DirectoryServices library. The issue is with the ValidateCredentials method of the PrincipalContext class, that are returning false for some accounts (I've checked them and works perfectly with all other services), it doesn't throw any Exception, just false. The code is simply as next:

```
public bool AuthenticateUser(string accountName, string password)
{
      var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
                                         _credentialsProvider.GetLdapServer(),
                                         _credentialsProvider.GetLdapSearchBase(),
                                         _credentialsProvider.GetBindUsername(),
                                         _credentialsProvider.GetBindPassword());

      return context.ValidateCredentials(accountName, password);
}
```

I've used also UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity to validate the existence of the account, I've tested the password in another domain services, and everything worked fine but the ValidateCredentials result.

I've tried with different `ContextOptions` values, also with different ways with the accountName (using NETBIOS format [DOMIAN\account], and using domain format [account@domain.any]), and the result is the same; some users authenticate and some not.

Comment: Look for patterns in the ones that fail. Is `_credentialsProvider.GetLdapServer()` always the same? Is the `accountName` always in the same format? Is the password actually accurate? You can also try using `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, accountName)` and see if that succeeds or throws an exception that might give you more information.

Comment: I see your update, but you will still need to find some pattern with those that fail and those that succeed. It's not just a bad username/password that will result in a `false` result, but a failure to connect properly will do it too.